# Digit sums as a possible simple cipher for orienteering

Tags: probability

This scenario is a case where I want to covertly confirm to team members a specific GPS coordinate location (like for an orienteering exercise) I have chosen, so they know when they have correctly identified the location. I want to give them some confidence that they are correct in choosing that location without giving away the location to those who do not yet know the location. I think a digit sum might work for this, practically, but I want to make sure it also makes sense mathematically.

As an example suppose I pick a number with a set format— like map coordinates- degrees, minutes, seconds. Latitude can be 6 “digits.” 00,00,00 with degrees up to 90 and the other fields up to 60. Longitude can be 7 digits or 000,00,00 with degrees up to 180 and other fields up to 60. I would assume positive numbers- north of equator and west of prime meridian. Zero is possible too.

What is the probability of getting a specific number pair (like 10, 20... or 12, 17) by by summing the digits of latitude, then longitude?

Say I pick a notable point in the US- represented by GPS coordinates. (Say, the Lincoln Memorial, but could be anywhere) then I add the sum of each of 6 digits of the latitude and get 22. Then I sum the 7 digits of the longitude and get 15. Assuming the sums of 22 and 15 are the result of my random map point selection, is there a way to determine the probability of those specific sums occurring together with respect to my chosen spot?

In short, if I’m in the field and I run the digit check and get 15,22– how confident can I be that it is not random, and that I am correct in the location?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I’m not a mathematician, so that’s tough!

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy because the distribution of digits is quite nonuniform.  If you picked places near where I live the latitude would always be $37$ (maybe $38$) and the longitude would be $121$ or $122$.  We can assume the least significant digit is reasonably uniform.  A lower bound comes from the fact that summing digits maintains the remainder on division by $9$, so you would expect an error to get the correct sum less than $\frac 19$ of the time.  With two coordinates, this says both will match less than $\frac 1{81}$ of the time.  If people transpose digits it will not catch the error.

Slightly more complicated to compute is the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), which is used with credit cards.  It will catch all single digit errors and all single transpositions.  It produces a single digit, so you would imagine the false positive rate for completely different input would be about $\frac 1{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

going further to digital root we get roughly 490 points per degree that can be confused in the lat, and 490 points in the long. for a grand total of 240100 confusing both per square degree. digit sum cut these to roughly 25 each way ( used pigeonhole on (60/14)). that's 625 points per square degree( 60 by 60 in pari gp actualy gets a maximum of 300 for digit sum 14).

`my(a=vector(28,i,0));for(x=1,60,for(y=1,60,a[sumdigits(x)+sumdigits(y)]++));a
%4 = [0, 4, 12, 25, 44, 70, 104, 139, 176, 214, 248, 275, 292, 300, 296, 278, 252, 220, 184, 147, 112, 82, 56, 35, 20, 10, 4, 1]`  now to weight by  degrees.

`my(a=vector(35,i,0));for(x=1,90,for(y=1,180,a[sumdigits(x)+sumdigits(y)]++));a
%7 = [0, 6, 19, 41, 74, 120, 181, 259, 356, 474, 598, 723, 843, 952, 1044, 1113, 1153, 1158, 1122, 1056, 967, 861, 744, 622, 501, 387, 286, 204, 140, 91, 55, 30, 14, 5, 1]`  so some points have as many as 104220000 points they could be confused for ( until if water or land is taken into account) but there are points that nobody could confuse.